# OnClick Handler overwriting previous value if using same handler for multiple DOM elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Swatches = (props) => {
  const options = props.options;
  const label = Object.keys(options);
  const values = Object.values(options);
  const colors = props.colors;
  const sizes = props.sizes;
  let selected = [];
  let a = {};
  const selecetedOption = (e) => {
     let index = selected.findIndex((x) => x.option_id === e.target.dataset.id);
    if (index == -1) {
      selected.push({
        option_id: e.target.dataset.id,
        option_value: e.target.dataset.value,
      });
    } else {
      selected[index].option_value = e.target.dataset.value;
    }
    console.log(selected);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {values.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          <div className="flex middle-xs mb-15">
            <div className="fs-16 fw-5 c-main-gray">
              Pick your <span className="option-label">{label}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          {label == "color" && colors?.options?.length > 0 && (
            <div className="flex flex-wrap size-unit-list">
              {colors?.options?.map((option, index) => (
                <React.Fragment key={index}>
                  {values[0].indexOf(parseInt(option.value)) > -1 && (
                    <div
                      className="fs-14 fw-5 c-dark-gray ta-c pt-6 pb-6 pl-10 pr-10 mw-40 mb-10 b-light-gray b-box size-button br-3 pos-relt mr-r-10 h-33 w-33"
                      style={{ backgroundColor: option?.label }}
                      data-id={colors.id}
                      data-value={option.value}
                      role="button"
                      onClick={selecetedOption}
                    ></div>
                  )}
                </React.Fragment>
              ))}
            </div>
          )}
          {label == "size" && sizes?.options?.length > 0 && (
            <div className="flex flex-wrap size-unit-list">
              {sizes?.options?.map((option, index) => (
                <React.Fragment key={index}>
                  {values[0].indexOf(parseInt(option.value)) > -1 && (
                    <div
                      className="fs-14 fw-5 c-dark-gray ta-c pt-6 pb-6 pl-10 pr-10 mw-40 mb-10 b-light-gray b-box size-button br-3 pos-relt mr-r-10"
                      data-id={sizes.id}
                      data-value={option.value}
                      role="button"
                      onClick={selecetedOption}
                    >
                      <span className="lh-ar-2 en-font">{option.label}</span>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </React.Fragment>
              ))}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Swatches;
```

When I and clicking on first element its working fine but when I click on second element and call onClick={selecetedOption} it overwrite previous values of result array and start it all over again.

Actual Result
when I click on colors, console.log(selected) giving below

```
`[
    {
        "option_id": "159",
        "option_value": "167"
    }
]`
```

but when i click on size, console.log(result) is giving

```
`[
    {
        "option_id": "93",
        "option_value": "59"
    }
]`
```

Expected Result
When i Click on colors

```
`[
    {
        "option_id": "159",
        "option_value": "167"
    }
]`
```

when i click on sizes It should be like below

```
`[
    {
        "option_id": "159",
        "option_value": "167"
    },
{
        "option_id": "93",
        "option_value": "59"
    }
]`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using useState for the array "selected" and spread operator

```
const [selected , setselected ] = useState([]); 
const selecetedOption = (e) => {
    setselected ({
      ...selected ,
      option_id: e.target.dataset.id,
      option_value: e.target.dataset.value,
    });   };
```

Comment: I did this
const selecetedOption = (e) => {
    setselected({
      ...selected,
      option_id: e.target.dataset.id,
      option_value: e.target.dataset.value,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selected);
  }, [selected]);

and in console i am getting data in below format  for every click 
{
    "option_id": "159",
    "option_value": "166"
}
but I want data like below if someone clicks on colors and size elements
[{
    "option_id": "159",
    "option_value": "166"
},
{
    "option_id": "93",
    "option_value": "81"
}]